# Is there a way to stop the (MMPCM) Silverlight Video Player at the end of the video?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using MMPCM Silverlight Video Player in a SharePoint 2010 site. The video is continuously looping. Is there a way to stop the player at the end of the video?